# Any particular reason why FaceBook's Subscribe Button isn't showing on my web page?

Tags: facebook, subscribe

I got this FaceBook profile for my upcoming website and I can't get the Subscribe button to show, NOT EVEN ON FaceBook's page!

http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100003492130845

Now, if you go here on FaceBook's page where we build the Subscribe button:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/

And add the above link, it will show nothing.

I enabled subscribing and I also created myself a page, linked to the same profile:

http://www.facebook.com/pages/Axonn-Says/372194956141393

But not even the page works ::- /.

LATER EDIT:

I temporarily added 2 other Subscribe buttons on my website to demonstrate that it works for example for Mark Zuck's page and to demonstrate that there are no JS conflicts. The 2 buttons appeared ok, but my button still didn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe functionality desired for user profiles, not Facebook Pages

From [Subscribe Button documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/)

> `href` - **profile URL of the user** to subscribe to. This must be a facebook.com profile URL.

Tagline from social plugins:

> The Subscribe button allows people to **subscribe to other Facebook users** directly from your site.

Actually Like (aka Fan) functionality (and also [Like Box Social Plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)) is used for same purpose for Facebook Pages.

Comment: Neither works. As I said, I also tried my profile URL, as mentioned in my question. To make matters worse, I also tried my personal account, http://www.facebook.com/axonn.echysttas and not even that one works: just try that link on FaceBook's Subscribe Button page link which is available in my question: it doesn't work. The axonn.echysttas is my personal FB page while AxonnSays I created especially for the website I'm preparing to launch. Nothing works. I enabled Subscriptions on both accounts.

Comment: This seems like an issue with your account (or it's settings) (it's working for all of my friends who have enabled subscriber, both timeline owners and people with old profiles). You can file a bug and see what officials say.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't file bugs ::- (. I requested to be a part of the Developers group (which has thousands of members), but no answer yet.

Comment: You don't need to be part on any group to file bug, just visit [Bug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Comment: Yeah, I've been there. But I can't figure out how to submit a new one! ::- ). It's just a list of bugs and I see no "Add" button or even some icon indicating I could interact with the list.

Comment: LOL I sincerely do not see any create button on that first page. But thank you for the URL. This one works. Now let me see if I can also actually submit a question with it, or end up in some permissions hell. LATER EDIT: I hit create, and its stuck at the progress GIF animation.

Comment: I was finally able to create the bug, but no answer for 4 days ::- (.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the code from the SUBSCRIBE BUTTON. But change "subscribe.php" to "like.php". Everything else is the same. You might have tried "likebox.php" but try this too.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea what you're talking about. There are no PHP files involved. I'm using this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/subscribe/ and this means that the JavaScript takes care of adding the button. And the button doesn't work. Period. Not even on their website, even though I enabled all necessary features. *sigh* FaceBook sucks.

Answer (score 0):

As Juicy Scripter pointed out, it is impossible to 'Subscribe' to pages. If you set it to a profile URL, make sure you have enabled Subscribers for that profile - as it isn't enabled by default.

To do that, open in your browser: http://www.facebook.com/YOUR_PROFILE_URL/subscribers
Click the Settings button, and make sure Subscribers is set to On.

Edit:

> I enabled subscribing and I also created myself a page, linked to the same profile:

Oops, silly me, I missed that bit

Comment: This feature continues to be broken. Tried reporting the bug, no answer back. FaceBook sucks.

Answer (score 0):

This is to address one part of your issue, namely the missing FaceBook 'Subscribe' button in your timeline.

I thought I had the same problem... but there was no problem at all.

I couldn't see the 'Subscribe' button on my profile page, but then I realized that potential subscribers CAN see it.

This is how to check: Click on the downarrow next to Home on the top right of a page in facebook, then 'Account Settings',  then at the bottom of the right pane there is a link: "Want to know what subscribers can see? View your public timeline."

If you click on that, you might see - as I did - that your Subscribe button is perfectly visible to visitors.